# Front page loads but other return 500 Internal Server Error on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, routes, hosting

I deployed my laravel 4.2 website on a shared hosting with ftp but the routes are not working. The fronp page loads fine but when i try to go to another page it returns "500 Internal Server Error". : It's reading the .htaccess file but i don't know if its correct. It's auto genereated from laravel. I uploaded it bellow. I also tried giving write permission to storage and bootstrap folders but it still doesn't work.

Edit: I noticed something interesting. if I go to www.example.com/test is returns the 500 internal error but if i go to www.example.com/index.php/test , now it loads correctly. Any idea how to fix it?

Edit2: IT WORKS. I just had to exclude index.php from the url with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

---

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

updated .htaccess file that fixed the problem

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You need to check your error log for the details of the error.

Comment: The php5_error.log it's not updating for some reason. I can only guess what is the problem.

Comment: Try putting a number sign in front of multiviews. So at the top #Options -MultiViews

Comment: It didn't work @Scott

Comment: What type of access do you have to the logs? Shared hosting I would imagine you do not have command line access? As w3dk mentioned, that would help pin point the error.

Comment: @Scott I don't have ssh. It's a budget hosting plan so I had to use ftp. There is a error log file in the root directory but it stopped updating for some reason. Maybe i'm just stupid and overloaded from dealing with problems all day.

Comment: @Scott I noticed something interesting. if I go to www.example.com/test is returns the 500 internal error but if i go to www.example.com/index.php/test , now it loads correctly. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Scott Thanks for help. I excluded index.php from the route with 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
And now it works

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Wish I could have helped more.